# How to open and append data in a log file in JMeter webdriver sampler?

Tags: jmeter, webdriver

How to open and append data in a log file in the JMeter Webdriver sampler?I don't want to use the WDS.log.info() method.Instead want to append the data in a file in a particular folder. I am using JMeter version 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
var log = new java.io.File('/path/to/your.log')
var newline = java.lang.System.lineSeparator()
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(log, 'message #1' + newline, true)
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(log, 'message #2' + newline, true)
```

The above code will add

```
message #1
message #2
```

to the file specified.

More information:

- [System.lineSeparator()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--)
- [FileUtils.writeStringToFile()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean))
- [Using Java From Scripts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html)
- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply execute groovy script to append to file:

```
File f = new File("c:/temp/hello.txt");
f.append("hello\n");
```

Comment: I am using javascript as the script language.

Comment: @RJM you can add JSR223 Pre/PostProcessor with this code